# Is there a way to configure the Auto Scaling Group termination policy when using Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

The ASG part of Beanstalk options does not have it listed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html?shortFooter=true#command-options-general-autoscalingasg - and neither does the rest of the page.

Right now I'm having to resort to manually editing the termination policy in the ASG page in EC2.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I use **.ebextensions** folder to configure my apps. Inside I have created a **termination.config** file containing this:

```
Resources:
      AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
        Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
        Properties:
          TerminationPolicies: [ "OldestInstance" ]
```